# How to get constants from a static class into a List<SelectListItem>

Tags: c#, selectlistitem

I have a static class with constants that I want to store in a list to be used in a DropDown

```
public static class DateFormatConstant
{
    [Display(Name = "DD/MM/YYYY")]
    public const string DayMonthYear = "dd/MM/yyyy";
    [Display(Name = "MM/DD/YYYY")]
    public const string MonthDayYear = "MM/dd/yyyy";
    [Display(Name = "YYYY/MM/DD")]
    public const string YearMonthDay = "yyyy/MM/dd";
    [Display(Name = "MM/DD/YY")]
    public const string MonthDayTwoDigitYear = "MM/dd/yy";
}
```

Is there a way to get them into a `List<SelectListItem>`?

Comment: What is a `selectlistitem`? Don't you mean a `List<string>`?

Comment: `var dateFormats = new List<string> { DateFormatConstant.DayMonthYear, DateFormatConstant.MonthDayYear, DateFormatConstant.YearMonthDay, DateFormatConstant.MonthDayTwoDigitYear };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [answer from @maembe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62204044) utilizing Reflection is a good way to go. But since you already are decorating your constants with the `Display` attribute I'll expand this solution to use the attribute. Note that I use LINQ's Query Syntax here as opposed to the Method Syntax in the other answer.

Here's my code:

```
var selectLisItems =
    from f in typeof(DateFormatConstant).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
    where f.IsLiteral && f.FieldType == typeof(string)
    from a in f.CustomAttributes
    where a.AttributeType == typeof(DisplayAttribute)
    let na = a.NamedArguments.First(x => x.MemberName == nameof(DisplayAttribute.Name))
    select new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = (string)na.TypedValue.Value,
        Value = (string)f.GetRawConstantValue()
    };

var list = selectLisItems.ToList();
```

What does it actually do? Let's look at the parts of the query.

```
    from f in typeof(DateFormatConstant).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
    where f.IsLiteral && f.FieldType == typeof(string)
```

Here I'm selecting all constants from the `DateFormatConstant` class that are of type `string`.

```
    from a in f.CustomAttributes
    where a.AttributeType == typeof(DisplayAttribute)
```

Now I'm limiting to constants that actually have the `Display` attribute. Note that the "real" type here is `DisplayAttribute`

```
    let na = a.NamedArguments.First(x => x.MemberName == nameof(DisplayAttribute.Name))
```

Next is going through the arguments of the attribute and search for `Name`. I can safely use `First` here because I already limited to the `DisplayAttribute` type and know therefore that it has a `Name` property.

```
    select new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = (string)na.TypedValue.Value,
        Value = (string)f.GetRawConstantValue()
    };

var list = selectLisItems.ToList();
```

At last I'm constructing `SelectListItem` from the attribute and the fields and create the desired `List<SelectListItem>` from the query.

**Note:** All this assumes that you want *all* string constants from your class to be contained in the list. If your class contains more constants that should go in different lists you can use the `GroupName` property of the `Display` attribute to group constants together. I'll leave it as an excercise to expand the code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it automatically, you would need to use reflection:

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> fields = typeof(DateFormatConstant).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
    .Where(f => f.IsLiteral && !f.IsInitOnly) // all the constant fields
    .Select(f => new SelectListItem() {    //convert to SelectListItem
            Text = ((string)f.GetRawConstantValue()).ToUpper(),
            Value = (string)f.GetRawConstantValue()
        });
```